# Proof verification: Elementary substructure contains aleph numbers

Tags: logic, solution-verification, set-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the lanuage consisting of the $\in$ symbol and let $\mathcal{A}$ be a structure which interprets $\in$ in the obvious way. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be an elementary substructure.

Q: As long as the domain of $\mathcal{A}$ is sufficiently large Von-Neumann universe, can we guarantee that $B$ will contain all of the aleph numbers up to and including $\aleph_\omega$?

I tried to prove it as follows: Let's say we want to prove that $\aleph_i \in B$. Then let $\phi(x)$ be a formula which expresses in formal set theoretic language that $x$ is $\aleph_i$. Now the  sentence $\exists y \phi(y)$ is true in $\mathcal{A}$, therefore it must also be true in $\mathcal{B}$. So there is some $b \in B$ such that $\mathcal{B} \models \phi[b]$ and $\mathcal{A} \models \phi[b]$. Since there is only one $a \in A$ such that $\mathcal{A}  \models \phi[a]$, we must have $a=b= \aleph_i$. QED.

Is the above correct? I'm skeptical because it seems just too simple. Also, it seems that by similar logic one could "prove" that $B$ contains ANY aleph number, but I think that's false because it might be a countable substructure.

If it makes any difference, we're working in ZF.

Comment: Is $A$ assumed to be a transitive set?

Comment: @MarkSaving I should probably add that assumption.

Comment: How do you know "$\exists y\phi(y)$" is true in $\mathcal{A}$? I think you're tacitly assuming that $\mathcal{A}\models\mathsf{ZF}$ (or something similar).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Well if $A$ is large enough so that $\aleph_i \in A$, then wouldn't that automatically guarantee $\mathcal{A} \models \exists y \phi(y)$?

Comment: There is a bit of a subtlety here which you have ignored that causes major problems. $A$ may be a transitive set which contains $\aleph_\omega$, but that does not mean that $A$ actually believes that $\aleph_2$ is indeed $\aleph_2$. It may be that there’s some countable ordinal $\beta \in A$, but there is no bijection $f : \omega \to \beta$ such that $f \in A$. So $A$ would not identify the true $\aleph_2$ as being $\aleph_2$ since $A$ believes that $\omega < |\beta| < |\aleph_2|$.

Comment: @MarkSaving I'm not sure I understand the subtlety. Which line of the "proof" is problematic? (And is there a way to fix it?)

Comment: @Pascal'sWager What do you mean by "sufficiently large?" I interpreted that as referring to cardinality, but there are arbitrarily high cardinality transitive sets not containing $\aleph_\omega$.

Comment: @Pascal'sWager You’ve shown that if $A \models isAleph1(a)$, then $a \in B$. But you haven’t shown that if $A \models isAleph1(a)$, then $a = \aleph_1$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Okay, perhaps I will need to change the initial assumptions. Would it be enough to assume $A$ is a Von-Neumann universe?

Comment: @MarkSaving So if I understand correctly, we might not have $\mathcal{A} \models isAleph1( \aleph_1)$?

Comment: @Pascal'sWager Correct.

Comment: The difference you ask for is that not every cardinal is definable without parameters. However, all $\aleph_n$, $\aleph_\omega$ and many others are, so they all belong to $B$ as long as $A$ identifies them correctly.